# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WsFederation

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a ASP.NET legacy project to which ADFS authentication needs to be added. So I did the same but when I run the application, I keep getting this error:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WsFederation, Version=5.2.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Here is my `web.config` entry for the said assembly

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WsFederation" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.3.0.0" newVersion="5.3.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

and my `packages.json` entry

```
 <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WsFederation" version="5.3.0" targetFramework="net452"/>
```

Why does the solution still search for version 5.2.0 when I refer to version 5.3.0?

Comment: Try removing the `bindingRedirect` entry; that can sometimes confuse things. (From personal experience)

Comment: Did not help, however thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I think you should provide more detials: target framework, if error happens in both debug or release mode, maybe you can share your csproj showing us the references...

Comment: Target framework is 4.5.2, happens in debug mode. Project is of asp.net template and doesn't have .csproj file

Comment: Issue is resolved after i updated this specific nuget package and its dependencies and downgraded to 5.3 as per the suggestion from the error .

Answer (score 0):

Check if the Top `<Configuration>` tag has this attribute

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0"
```

If you do, you will need to remove this in order for the BindingRedirect to work. More info here https://stackoverflow.com/a/37722093/1628611